# What is the best approach to setup a Linux environment in Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently running Windows 10, and have activated WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) and installed Ubuntu distro but is not working off the self with Windows Chrome browser when using Jupyter notebook and in general libraries that call Chrome as it gets confused between the /usr/bin/chrome in Linux and the Windows executable for Chrome (or my setup is incomplete of course :) )

I've managed to overcome some issues like launching Jupyter in Windows Chrome browser from Ubuntu terminal but I keep hitting other issues when using bespoke libraries etc...

It'd be great if someone can weigh in on the options below and why you would choose one over the other? e.g.

- **Option 1** - Setup using WSL and Linux distro
- **Option 2** - Setup via VM in gloud from Windows machine (does it have to be cloud or can be local?)
- **Option 3** - Setting up dual boot on my machine - I'm aware of this option, but have left it last to be honest
- **Option 4** - Setup a on
           separate hardware i.e. spare laptop/desktop - I also understand this
           option but haven't got a spare one :)

Also, are there any options I'm missing?

I was wondering if someone can point me to the right direction and/or provide some relevant links for detailed implementation of the suggested option?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your planned use and expectations.

- *Are you planning to use Tensorflow and GPU hardware with Jupyter?* If
  so, I'd recommend option 3 as hardware support is better on native Linux.
- *Is performance a key consideration?* Option 2 is a very reasonable choice if you are not trying to get every last oz of performance out of your hardware.

An additional option you may not have considered:

If your aim is try a few Linux distributions to see what you like, consider downloading a live USB distribution. You could dual boot into Linux from removable USB media if you want something more semi-permanent (but don't want to partition / potentially corrupt your system drive).

Answer (score -1):

Actually I am using triple boot with Windows 10, Elementary OS and ArcoLinux. Iy is not so really hard, but some steps must be done like tuning off fast boot in power management in Windows 10 and disabling Secure Boot in BIOS for some distros. Elementary OS is working fine with Secure Boot, however you must bare in mind that knowledge about which firmware must be installed in Linux is a must have, to let the system properly work after the installation process.

You can use the Virtual Machine and make a shared directory between machine and Windows, which let you to share files, however machine inside the machine will always eat more resources than system working on a hardware.

Separate machine with Linux is the best option just because you will be sure that you will not damage Windows and besides it is much easier to install it on a machine without Windows or when you can completely remove Windows and install Linux. But in this case it is worth to take care about some share solution between Windows and Linux machines if you need it.

That is my point of view for this case.